# JavaScript/jQuery variable scope in class (this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop

I'm writing simple slider for my website. This slider contains list items. I want to use OOP approach.

My actual code:

```
var miniSlider = function(objId)
    {
        this.obj = $("#" + objId);
        this.obj.settings = [];
        this.obj.settings['items'] = $('ul li', this.obj).length;

        this.pagerNext = this.obj.find("i.next");
        this.pagerPrev = this.obj.find("i.prev");
        this.pagerNext.on("click", function() {
        alert(this.obj.settings['items']);
        });
    };
```

I can invoke a few other sliders (yes, that's why I introduced a class):

```
miniSlider("mini-slider");
```

The problem is that when I'm in jQuery this.pagerNext.on("click", function() { }); ***this*** is no longer my object but - it's become a clicked element. How can I access this.obj.settings after click in a well done way (and with multi sliders support)?

**EDIT:**

Here is a full code created with a cooperation with SOF community :)

```
var MiniSlider = function(objId)
{
    this.obj = $("#" + objId);

    this.obj.settings = {
        items: $("ul li", this.obj).length,
        autoChangeTime: 8000
    };
    this.obj.activeElement = null;

    this.pagerNext = this.obj.find("i.next");
    this.pagerPrev = this.obj.find("i.prev");

    var self = this;

    this.pagerNext.on("click", function() {

        self.obj.activeElement = $('li.active', self.obj);

        if(self.obj.settings.items > 0)
        {
            if(self.obj.activeElement.is(':last-child')) 
            { 
                $('li.active', self.obj).removeClass('active');
                $('li', self.obj).first().addClass('active');
            } 
            else 
            {
                self.obj.activeElement.next().addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
        }
    }
    });
    this.pagerPrev.on("click", function() 
    {
        self.obj.activeElement = $('li.active', self.obj);

        if(self.obj.settings.items > 0)
        {
            if(self.obj.activeElement.is(':first-child')) 
            { 
                self.obj.activeElement.removeClass('active');
                $('li', self.obj).last().addClass('active');
            } 
            else 
            {
                self.obj.activeElement.prev().addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
            }
        }
    });
    this.obj.parent().on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseenter') 
        {
            $(this).addClass('stop');
        }
        else 
        {
            $(this).removeClass('stop'); 
        }
    });
    setInterval(function() {
        if(self.obj.settings.items > 0 && !self.obj.parent().hasClass("stop"))
        {
            self.pagerNext.click();
        }
    }, this.obj.settings.autoChangeTime);

    };
```

and invoke:

```
new MiniSlider("mini-slider");
```

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but if you plan to instantiate more than one of these guys you should use the 'new' keyword, as in new MiniSlider("mini-slider1"); Also if you use it like that make the m uppercase to indicate this function should be used as a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alex gave you the solution to the `this` problem in your callback, but there is another problem in your code.

You are calling the `miniSlider()` function without a `new` operator:

```
miniSlider("mini-slider");
```

That means that inside the function, `this` is not a unique object, but is actually the `window` object!

You need to use the `new` operator to create an individual object for each call:

```
new miniSlider("mini-slider");
```

But you should also change the name of this function to follow the JavaScript convention that constructors begin with a capital letter. Call it `MiniSlider` and use it like so:

```
new MiniSlider("mini-slider");
```

If you follow this convention (which most experienced JavaScript programmers do), it will help you remember when to use `new`. If the function begins with a capital letter, it's a constructor and you need to use `new` with it. Otherwise, you don't.

If you'd like to be able to use your constructor *without* `new`, that is also possible with a bit more code, e.g.:

```
function MiniSlider( objId ) {
    if( this == window ) return new MiniSlider( objId );
    // the rest of your constructor code goes here
}
```

But generally people don't bother with that and just use the initial capital letter on the constructor as a reminder to use `new`.

Also, as a suggestion, I like to use a meaningful name when I save `this` in a variable, and then I use that name consistently instead of using `this` at all. Doing it this way it might look like:

```
var miniSlider = function(objId) {
    var slider = this;

    slider.obj = $("#" + objId);
    slider.obj.settings = [];
    slider.obj.settings['items'] = $('ul li', slider.obj).length;

    slider.pagerNext = slider.obj.find("i.next");
    slider.pagerPrev = slider.obj.find("i.prev");
    slider.pagerNext.on("click", function() {
        alert(slider.obj.settings['items']);
    });
};
```

Why do I prefer that approach over using `this` in most places and another variable like `self` where you need it? This way I don't have to remember which to use: I can *always* use `slider` in the code instead of `this`. (Of course you could use `self` or any other name; I just like to have a more meaningful name if I'm going to the trouble of making up a name at all.)

Another minor problem in the code is in these two statements:

```
    slider.obj.settings = [];
    slider.obj.settings['items'] = $('ul li', slider.obj).length;
```

You shouldn't use an `Array` when you are going to be giving it named properties like this. Use an `Object` instead. Arrays should only be used when you have numeric indexes like 0, 1, 2, etc. And with an object literal you can set the property at the same time:

```
    slider.obj.settings = {
        items: $('ul li', slider.obj).length
    };
```

Also, when you use that property:

```
        alert(slider.obj.settings['items']);
```

you can write it more simply as:

```
        alert(slider.obj.settings.items);
```

Either way it does the same thing.

Comment: Glad to help. Happy hacking! :-)

Comment: Looks good! One little suggestion would be to move the `var self = this;` to the very top of the `MiniSlider` function, and then to use `self` everywhere in the function instead of `this`. That way you don't have to think about "where can I use `this` and where do I need to use `self`?" You can simply use `self` *everywhere* in the function.

Answer (score 2):

Save a reference to this in a local variable, and use that variable instead of `this` in the nested function.

```
var self = this;
this.pagerNext.on("click", function() {
  alert(self.obj.settings['items']);
});
```

Comment: I thought about it, but won't I have problems if I run a few sliders?

Comment: @PAM: No; it;s a _local_ variable.

Comment: @PAM Nope. The function you make is bound to the scope you made it in.