# JavaScript Own class: merge arrays with settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, merge

Lately with help of SOF I wrote [simple slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477663/javascript-jquery-variable-scope-in-class-this) for my webpage. I need to run a few sliders with different settings. I need to merge arrays with settings put in class constructor. Settings placed in here should overwrite default settings.

My code:

```
var MiniSlider = function(objId, settings)
{
    this.obj = $("#" + objId);
    var self = this;

    self.obj.settings = {
        items: $("ul li", self.obj).length,
        autoChangeTime: 8000,
        animation: 'horizontal'
    };

    if(settings)
    {
        $.merge(self.obj.settings, settings)
    }
    ... rest of the code at link [1]
};
```

And invocation:

```
new MiniSlider("mini-slider-2", [{animation: 'vertical'}]);
```

With this I get that:
[image: Firebug console.log of self.obj.settings]

Animation should be set to 'vertical'. A also tryied:

```
new MiniSlider("mini-slider-2", {animation: 'vertical'});
```

This don't work too. Any advices how to merge this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.merge is for arrays. You should use $.extend (because `settings` is an object)

```
$.extend(self.obj.settings, settings)
```

and invocation

```
new MiniSlider("mini-slider-2", {animation: 'vertical'});
```