# jQuery sliderDown work but slideUp don't

Tags: jquery, animation, slider, slideup

I wrote a simple slider with a help of SOF community. Now I'm trying to add to it some fancy animations. Slider can handle: horizontal and vertical sliding. I have problems with slideUp effect when slideDown works completly good. When I click icon for item to slideUp, next item is showing up without any animation.

My code:

```
self.nextItem = function()
{
    if(self.obj.activeElement.is(':last-child')) 
    {
        $('li.active', self.obj).removeClass('active');

        if(self.obj.settings.animation === "horizontal")
        {
            $('li', self.obj).first().toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000, function() {
                $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('li', self.obj).first().slideUp('slow', function() {
                $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
            });
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        self.obj.find("li").removeClass("active");

        if(self.obj.settings.animation === "horizontal")
        {
            self.obj.activeElement.next().toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000, function() {
                $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
            });
        }
        else 
        {
            self.obj.activeElement.next().slideUp('slow', function() {
                $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
            });
        }
    }
},
```

Every next and prev item is hidden when clicking next/prev pager icon. The whole code of slider (without animation support) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477663/javascript-jquery-variable-scope-in-class-this). At first I didn't know that I will need to animate so item are showint/hiding by CSS (.active { display: block}) and becouse of that I have to remove inline style.

HTML is simple:

```
   <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
```

I use slideDown effect (other part of code) with it and it works good.

**EDIT:**

At first I thougt that including a whole code isn't a good idea so I've placed only part where I think is a problem. But if you want here is a full version:

```
var MiniSlider = function(objId, settings)
{
this.obj = $("#" + objId);
var self = this;

self.obj.settings = {
    items: $("ul li", self.obj).length,
    autoChangeTime: 8000,
    animation: 'horizontal'
};

if(settings instanceof Object)
{
    $.extend(self.obj.settings, settings);
}

self.obj.activeElement = null;

self.pagerNext = self.obj.find("i.next");
self.pagerPrev = self.obj.find("i.prev");



self.pagerNext.on("click", function() {

    self.obj.activeElement = $('li.active', self.obj);

    if(self.obj.settings.items > 0)
    {
        self.nextItem();
    }
});
self.pagerPrev.on("click", function() 
{
    self.obj.activeElement = $('li.active', self.obj);

    if(self.obj.settings.items > 0)
    {
        self.prevItem();
    }
});
self.obj.parent().on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseenter') 
    {
        $(this).addClass('stop');
    }
    else 
    {
        $(this).removeClass('stop'); 
    }
});

self.prevItem = function()
{
    if(self.obj.activeElement.is(':first-child')) 
    {
        self.obj.activeElement.removeClass('active');

        if(self.obj.settings.animation === "horizontal")
        {
            $('li', self.obj).last().toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000, function() {
                $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('li', self.obj).last().slideDown('slow', "linear", function() {
                $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
            });
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        self.obj.find("li").removeClass("active");

        if(self.obj.settings.animation === "horizontal")
        {
            self.obj.activeElement.prev().toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000, function() {
                $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
            });
        }
        else
        {
            self.obj.activeElement.prev().slideDown('slow', "linear", function() {
                $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
            });
        }
    }
},
self.nextItem = function()
{
    if(self.obj.activeElement.is(':last-child')) 
    {
        $('li.active', self.obj).removeClass('active');

        if(self.obj.settings.animation === "horizontal")
        {
            $('li', self.obj).first().toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000, function() {
                $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('li', self.obj).first().slideUp('slow', function() {
                $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
            });
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        self.obj.find("li").removeClass("active");

        if(self.obj.settings.animation === "horizontal")
        {
            self.obj.activeElement.next().toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000, function() {
                $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
            });
        }
        else 
        {
            self.obj.activeElement.next().slideUp('slow', function() {
                $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
            });
        }
    }
},
setInterval(function() {
    if(self.obj.settings.items > 0 && !self.obj.parent().hasClass("stop"))
    {
        self.pagerNext.click();
    }
}, self.obj.settings.autoChangeTime);

};
```

CSS:

```
div div.block-content.mini-slider ul li {
    display:none;
}
.block-content.mini-slider ul li.active {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: In order to help you one should take to many steps. You don't even include whole code, not to mention no ready to play fiddle. Not interesting.

Comment: Full version is here now. Show your interest and please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
self.obj.activeElement.next().slideUp('slow', function() {
      $(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
});
```

`SlideUp` is for hiding elements, not for showing. This code clearly hides the next element. But the next element **is already hidden**. This code `self.obj.activeElement.next().slideUp('slow'` actually does nothing.

After hiding is finished, you add the `active` class to it to display as block. That's why it shows up without animation. Because your code to display it is actually:

```
$(this).addClass('active').removeAttr("style")
```

Comment: Thanks, Slide Up is for hiding elements, not for showing - that clears the matters up.